# Get matching values of two objects

Tags: javascript, loops, filter

I have an object `inboundTransfer` which contains an unknown number of keys. I would like to get all values from the `itemNumbersList` properties which match the values on an array `Object.keys(selectedItems)`. The data that I receive looks a little something like this:

```
const selectedItems = {
    'nameX': {
      propert1: 'value1',
      property2: 'value2,
        ...
    }
  },
  'nameY': {
    ...
  },
  'nameT': {
    ...
  }

const inboundTransfers = {
  0: {
    property1: 'value1',
    itemNumbersList: ['nameX', 'nameY', 'nameZ'],
  },
  1: {
    property2: 'value2',
    itemNumbersList: ['nameK', 'nameJ', 'nameT']
  },
  ...
}

const isOnTransferlist = Object.keys(inboundTransfers)
  .map((transfer) => Object.values(inboundTransfers[transfer].itemNumbersList)
    .some((item) => Object.keys(selectedItems)
      .indexOf(item) >= 0));
```

Obviously, I currently only check if the value is on both lists or not. Ideally, I would like to get the value itself. How could I achieve that? I tried using `.filter` instead of `map` but with no success.
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try writing a more general function, because it feels like your indices are confusing and making this more complicated than it actually is

Comment: Do u want to capture the values from arrays ?

Comment: @GalAbra I'm not sure if I understand how I can make this more general since it's probably the complexity of these objects that make it so hard for me to solve.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine Yes, I want to capture the values of `itemNumbersList` that match the `Object.keys()` of `selectedItems`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this function and I test it, it works well.

```
 function match() {
    const selectedItems = {
      a: "a1",
      b: "b1",
    };
    const inboundTransfers = {
      0: {
        items: ["a", "b"],
      },
      1: {
        items: ["c", "b"],
      },
    };

    const capturedValues = []; // founded items store

    [...Object.keys(selectedItems)].forEach((arrKey) => {
      for (let [key, items] of Object.entries(inboundTransfers)) {
        Object.values(items).forEach((item) => {
          item.forEach((i) => {
            if (i === arrKey) {
              capturedValues.push(i);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
    // Remove redundant values
    console.log([...new Set(capturedValues)]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that works, but it's not very elegant, I guess:

```
const list = [];

Object.keys(inboundTransfers)
  .forEach((transfer) => {
    Object.values(inboundTransfers[transfer].itemNumbersList)
      .forEach((item) => {
        if (Object.keys(selectedItems).includes(item)) {
          list.push(item);
         }
   });
});
```